# Updating <li> text using JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I trying to update dynamically added li text (html code) with the JSON data as below script, but the update method are not working, could you help me to check?

```
City
<input type="text" id="cinput">
<br>
<input type="button" id="cadd" value="Add">
<input type="button" id="cup" value="Update">
<div class="clista">
<ul class="lista inset" id="citem">
    <li data-val="Campinas">Campinas [T:00ºC H:00%]<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('Remover?')){parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)}">   <span style="float:right;"><b>[X]</b></span></a>

    </li>
    <li data-val="Sao Paulo">Sao Paulo [T:00ºC H:00%]<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('Remover?')){parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)}">   <span style="float:right;"><b>[X]</b></span></a>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#cadd").on("click", function () {
var cinput = document.getElementById("cinput").value;
var msg = "'Remover?'";
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cinput + "&units=metric", function (data) {
    var cdados = ('T:' + data.main.temp + 'ºC H:' + data.main.humidity + '%');
    $('#citem').append('<li data-val="' + cinput + '">' + cinput + "  [" + cdados + ']<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm(' + msg + ')){parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)}">   <span style="float:right;"><b>[X]</b></span></li>');
    document.getElementById("cinput").value = "";
});
});

$("#cup").on("click", function () {
    var cidade = '';
var oldText = '';
var novotxt = '';
var msg = "'Remover?'";
var Link = ('<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm(' + msg + ')){parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)}">   <span style="float:right;"><b>[X]</b></span></a>');

$('.clista li').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    cidade = $(this).data('val');
    oldText = $(this).html();

    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cidade + "&units=metric", function (data) {
        var cdados = ('T:' + data.main.temp + 'ºC H:' + data.main.humidity + '%');
        novotxt = cidade + " [" + cdados + "] ";
        alert(novotxt);
        $this.html(function (index, html) {
            return html.replace(oldText, novotxt + Link);
        });
    });
});
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fabiobraglin/rcheaowx/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hitting an asynchronous issue here.  You have `$.each` and within that you're setting `oldText` and trying to use it's value within the callback of `getJSON`.  However, the entirety of the `$.each` loop will run before any of the `getJSON` callbacks are run, so `oldText` will end up being set to the final element in the collection for ALL of the callbacks, so it will only ever be correct for the final element.

There's two things to note here: the `html` parameter of this callback:

```
$this.html(function (index, html) {
    return html.replace(oldText, novotxt + Link);
});
```

should be functionally equivalent to what you're trying to use `oldText` for.  However, the element's contents are also cleared out before this callback is run, and whatever you return from it will be the entire contents of the element, so there's no need to try to replace the `oldText` in this way.  Just return your new content:

```
$this.html(function (index, html) {
    return novotxt + Link;
});
```

If you do find youself in a situation where the variables from the loop need to be available within the callback, you can create a closure as follows:

```
$('.clista li').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    cidade = $(this).data('val');
    oldText = $(this).html();

    (function getData(_oldText, _cidade) {
        $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + _cidade + "&units=metric", function(data) {
            var cdados = ('T:' + data.main.temp + 'ºC H:' + data.main.humidity + '%');
            novotxt = _cidade + " [" + cdados + "] ";
            alert(novotxt);
            $this.html(function(index, html) {
                return html.replace(_oldText, novotxt + Link);
            });
        });
    })(oldText, cidade);
});
```

Comment: Tks dude... In true, my script have two similar issues, one of them is this return that you mentioned... another one is with the city name (var cidade), so I'm now receiving this from JSON too...  Tks a lot!

Comment: I didn't notice that variable being used inside the callback, but yes - exact same issue

Comment: I'll update my answer with another alternative way of making those variables available, should they ever be needed